# Android NDK code analysis not using defined variables

Tags: android, android-ndk, analyzer

I think this problem started when upgrading to the Juno Eclipse. I believe the C/C++ build environment was probably upgraded as well at the same time.  The NDK was *not* upgraded.

We have a large mass of C code that compiles under several platforms.  We are using the crystax-ndk (r6) to compile our C++ code.  To know when we are compiling for Android, we have defined the following in the Android.mk

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK \
            -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL \
                 ...
```

Then in some files we will include different headers depending upon the platform

```
#ifdef ANDROID_NDK
     ...
```

Our code compiles just fine and seems to run fine.  However, when opening certain files the C/C++ code analyzer will find many errors.  This appears to be because the analyzer doesn't know about the ANDROID_NDK defined variable.

Any idea why the code analyzer is not using the same #defines as the compiler?  The code is almost uneditable with all the bogus errors the analyzer is reporting.

Comment: What analyzer?  At any rate, it is probably not fully parsing your Android.mk, if it is even attempting to at all.  You may have to pass it the applicable defines in some other way.

Comment: It is just the standard analyzer that comes with the C/C++ add on for Eclipse (or maybe it gets replaced when using the NDK).  There doesn't seem to be any thing in the project properties to set the analyzer so I guess it is just the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw you're comment about the analyzer you were refering to.

Eclipse CDT (C/C++ Development Toolkit) does not support parsing Android.mk yet neither does the NDK plugin add that functionality at the time of writing this.

Possible (ugly/annoying) workaround: Set up a header file setting the defines you are missing and include that header file to all files.

Comment: OK, that explains it.  For the time being I've just turned off most of the analyzer warning/errors so they don't get in my way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS` for C++ files and `LOCAL_CFLAGS` for C files in your Android.mk

Comment: As a test I duplicated the LOCAL_CFLAGS and called the dup LOCAL_CPPFLAGS.  Doing this didn't help.  I wouldn't think it would since C is a subset of C++ and LOCAL_CFLAGS is generally inherited when compiling C++.  Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: You are right, this has changed after android-ndk-1.5_r1. Since then `LOCAL_CFLAGS` is used for C/C++ and `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS` for C++ only